# Allow the user to send data to a database once per shift (once a day and once a night)

Tags: c#, sql

Hi everyone I'm new to c# and sql, I'm creating a windows application in c# that will allow the user not to insert same info in a database per shift between 7am and 7pm, the application must allow the user not to insert same info between this time interval and  same thing for night between 7pm and am....if the user tries to insert same data between this interval a message should pop up  that says 'information already exist for this shift'.

Here is my code so far for a <kbd>SAVE</kbd> button it can insert to a database I need someone who will help where and how can I add this function to allow the user not to insert same info in a database per shift between 7am and 7pm or if there is another way of doing it.  Can someone help me?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //................INSERT TO DATABASE...........................................................





        if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox1.Text)) & (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox10.Text)) & (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox9.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox6.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox8.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox13.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox7.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text))& (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text)))


        {
            string buffer = textBox10.Text;
            string buffer1 = textBox9.Text;
            string buffer2 = textBox6.Text;
            string buffer3 = textBox7.Text;
            string buffer4 = textBox8.Text;

            double val = Double.Parse(buffer, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double val1 = Double.Parse(buffer1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double val2 = Double.Parse(buffer2, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

             double val3 = Double.Parse(buffer3, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

             double val4 = Double.Parse(buffer4, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            if (val > 59 && val < 161 && val1 > 99 && val1 < 301 &&  val2>2&&val2<7  && val3>2 && val3<7 && val4>2 && val2<4)
            {


                float em1 = float.Parse(textBox6.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                float em2 = float.Parse(textBox7.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                float em3 = float.Parse(textBox8.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                float ava = float.Parse(textBox13.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                int bond = int.Parse(textBox9.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                int feed = int.Parse(textBox10.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



                string Connection = @"Data Source=NZUZO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Checksheet;Integrated Security=True";



                 string query = "insert into SJB (Machine_Cleanliness,Safety_System,Single_Mode,SJB_Fixture,Feed_Pressure,Bond_Height,Line_NO,Machine_NO,Product,Suspension,Capilary_Lifetime,EM_Trial1,EM_Trial2,EM_Trial3,Avarage,EN,Shift) values(@Machine_C ,@Safety, @SingleMode,@SJB_Fixture,'" + feed + "','" + bond + "','" + this.textBox12.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox11.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + em1 + "','" + em2 + "','" + em3 + "','" + ava + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.label5.Text + "')";


                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection);
                SqlCommand conn1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                //select getdate()");
                conn1.Connection = conn;
                //String selection = new string(MyChar, 1);

                //conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Safety", selection);

                SqlDataReader myReader;
               // conn1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("Checksheet1", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })

               // recordCount > 0;



                // radioButton6 = radioButton6.checked;

                if (radioButton6.Checked)
                {
                    // selection = "G";
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Safety", "G");
                }
                else if (radioButton5.Checked)


                    // selection = "N";
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Safety", "N");

                if (radioButton11.Checked)
                {
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine_C", "G");
                }
                else if (radioButton12.Checked)

                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine_C", "N");

                if (radioButton13.Checked)
                {
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SingleMode", "G");
                }
                else if (radioButton14.Checked)

                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SingleMode", "N");

                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SJB_Fixture", "G");
                }
                else if (radioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SJB_Fixture", "N");
                }


                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                   // conn1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myReader = conn1.ExecuteReader();



                    MessageBox.Show("Machine Checked......");

                    this.Close();




                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
               //         conn1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Line_No",textBox12);
               //          bool test=false;
               //int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

               // test = (myReader !=null && myReader.HasRows);







                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error.... Invalid Value in The check List.", "Check Sheet", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Submit Checklist...Please check for empty space", "Check Sheet", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't shoot us with your TITLE. We are good people.

Comment: First of all don't use tags in your title, Now my opnion. What you could do is make an boolean and call that shift. Then make a date time and set that the the times. Then when a user inserts data the boolean goes on false and then the user cant insert data until the time you've set

Comment: Also please change the names of you components it makes the code very unclear. if the textfield has to have a password in it, call it passwordTextbox. Its much easier that way

Comment: In addition to the other advice, please also fully use Parameters for input values to your SQL. Currently you have partial SQL-Injection risk due to mixing parameters and dynamically build SQL.

Comment: thank you CKY its a good idea of using boolean....let me do it and get back if i found any problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add another call to the database checking if there already row under the condition. For example:

```
select * from table where user_id = 10;
```

If rows returns is mean the user already insert data to the table, you can also make check about the specific dates the user was insert...

Answer (score 0):

Alright just a simple solution to this problem, atleast i think its a simple solution ;).

First of all just give the textboxes names. Its easier to read and if somethings wrong you understand faster why its goeing wrong.

So if you have a textbox that is used for a username just do it like this:

```
string username = usernameTextbox.Text;
```

Then why so many buffer?
Just make a `List<string> buffer = new List<string>`
Here's a example about the list:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Now to awnser the question, You have to options the one that Proxytype pointed out.

And you could insert a datetime into your database when the data is added. Then when you get another request check if an x amount of time has passed and if it has do something if otherwise dont do anything and point it out to the user

Comment: thanks for the advice guys...i will rename textbox fields  and for buffer its just a variable a declare so that i can able to convert string to integer and be able to use logical operator && to check for condition

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to put the check based on time then you can put a check with system datetime property.